# How can I connect from one MySQL server to another MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to setup something in MySQL like a MS-SQL Link Server? I would like to connect to another MySQL server so that something like this query works.

```
select a.*, b.* 
from srv1.db1.tbl1 t1 inner join 
     srv2.db2.tbl2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 2):

You could setup the remote tables as a [FEDERATED table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html).